# decoding json array object response

Tags: php, json, twitter

I already checked previous all thread but no luck.

I am getting json response like this: http://pastebin.com/HS0UhYat for `var_dump($tweets5);`

code:

```
//$tweetid = "200582436";
$tweets5 = $connection->get("https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/retweets/".$tweetid.".json?count=1");
var_dump($tweets5);
$tweets5 = json_decode($tweets5,true);
echo $tweets5[retweeted_status][user][name];
echo $tweets5->retweeted_status->user->name;
echo "$tweets5<br><br>";
```

I want to get each value username, id etc seperately. how to to this?

Answer (score 1):

you can use a simple foreach on your json object:

```
foreach($tweets5[0] as $tweet) {
    echo $tweet['user']['name'];
}
```

Comment: still no luck, even `echo $tweet['retweeted_status']['user']['name'];
` does not display any result

Comment: looking better at your dump, maybe you have to cycle on $tweets5[0], not on $tweets5